# What is in your JavaScript development toolbox?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I have to do some JavaScript in the future, so it is time to update my toolbox. Right now I use Firefox with some addons:

- JavaScript Shell from https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/webdevel.html
- Firefox Dom Inspector
- Firebug
- Greasemonkey
- Stylish

I plan to use [Venkman Javascript debugger](http://www.hacksrus.com/~ginda/venkman/)  as well as [jsunit](https://github.com/pivotal/jsunit) and [js-lint](http://jslint.com/).

For programming I'm stick with vim.

So what other tools do you use when developing JavaScript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use both Firefox and IE for Web Development and a few add-ons in each:

**Firefox:**

- [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843)
- [Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60)

**Internet Explorer:**

- [IE Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359)
- [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/)
- Visual Studio for JS Debugging

Answer (score 3):

I sometimes use Emacs with Steve Yegge's [js2-mode](http://code.google.com/p/js2-mode/), evaluating code with [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) & John Resig's [env.js](http://ejohn.org/blog/bringing-the-browser-to-the-server/) to load jQuery or Prototype in my standalone scripts.

This allows me to explore javascript, jQuery, and Prototype outside of a browser.

Example:

```
var window;
load("Library/env.js");
window.location = 'index.html'; // Load the page 'index.html'

print($('aForm').id); // Play with the Dom in a standalone script!
```

Answer (score 1):

1. [Web Developer Toolbar (Firefox Addon)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60)
2. [Nikhil's Web Development Helper (IE Toolbar)](http://projects.nikhilk.net/WebDevHelper/)

Answer (score 1):

**Firefox:**

- [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) - Invaluable for debugging markup and code while testing ideas directly in the browser

  - [Rainbow for Firebug](http://xrefresh.com/rainbow) - JavaScript syntax highlighting
  - [Pixel Perfect](http://www.pixelperfectplugin.com/) - Overlay images on any page, make it match the design on every pixel
- [Web Developer Toolbar](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) - Just about any tool you can think of
- [Firecookie](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firecookie/) - Manage your cookies
- [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) - Suggests how to boost the download performance

Windows-only:

- [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/) - A great HTTP proxy with debugging capabilities

**Internet Explorer:**
  - [Web Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=E59C3964-672D-4511-BB3E-2D5E1DB91038&displaylang=en) - Missing a few things but still very complete

Answer (score 1):

1. Firebug on Firefox
2. IE Web Developer toolbar on IE
3. JS Lint

Answer (score 0):

A couple more::

1. IE Explorer Toolbar
2. Firefox Developer Toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Best way to debug JavaScript in **Internet Explorer** is to use [Visual Web Developer Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vwd/).

If you like a **cross browser** logging solution check out [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html)!